# what this mean "Code 220 Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."

Tags: php, twitter

I had program an PHP site with twitter api. for a time it was working will but today it show me this error:

I'm trying to add a tweet via '1.1/statuses/update' and my app is configured for both read and write operations.

> ["code"]=>
>       int(403)
>       ["response"]=>
>       string(92) "{"errors":[{"code":220,"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource."}]}"

what are the most problem cost this error?

Comment: Have you tried [**this**](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/23239) ?

Comment: I read this page before. I update my Question.